# Code debugging, led control by date from file, Python

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3, led

Fixed code again, now leds working as they have to, i don't know why all Trues and Falses are upside down, because, where should be True is False and vice versa.

## But there is one problem: if leds were turned on by earlier and don't have to glow by condition, they won't turn off until starts other (new) condition when they have to turn on. Where is the problem?

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SDL_DS1307

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)



LED_R = 17
LED_G = 27
LED_B = 22


GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)


filename = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%SRTCTest") + ".txt"
starttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

ds1307 = SDL_DS1307.SDL_DS1307(1, 0x68)
ds1307.write_now()

while True:
    currenttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    deltatime = currenttime - starttime
        data=time.strftime("%Y"+"%m"+"%d"+"%H"+"%M")
   
        with open('data.txt') as f:
                for line in f:
                        parts=line.split()                               
                        if parts[0]<=(data)<=parts[1]:
                                if parts[2]=='100':
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_R, False)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_G, True)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_B, True)
                                elif parts[2]=='010':
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_R, True)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_G, False)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_B, True)
                                elif parts[2]=='001':
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_R, True)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_G, True)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_B, False)
                                elif parts[2]=='110':
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_R, False)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_G, True)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_B, False) 
                                elif parts[2]=='101':
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_R, True)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_G, False)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_B, False)
                                elif parts[2]=='101':
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_R, False)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_G, False)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_B, True)
                                elif parts[2]=='111':
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_R, False)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_G, False)
                                    GPIO.putput(LED_B, False)
                                else:
                                        GPIO.output(LED_R, True)
                                        GPIO.output(LED_G, True)
                                        GPIO.output(LED_B, True)
                        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: You have defined LED_R G B as 17 27 22. Why do you still use 17 27 22 in your following lines? Who was your programming teacher?

Comment: Google, was my teacher

Comment: If you replace all numbers by the LED_x equivalent, you should see the error.

Comment: I have corrected the code, 17, 22, 27 was replaced by LER_R, LED_G, LED_B , but all the same as was, i don't know, how to edit the code, if time is ended leds turns off, because, when if ends leds still on, they have to turn off, but how?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling GPIO.cleanup immediately after writing to the LEDs.  That switches all the GPIO you are using to be inputs rather than outputs.

I am surprised you don't get error messages when you run the code.  Perhaps the GPIO.setwarnings call is hiding the errors.

The simplest fix is to delete the GPIO.cleanup line.

Comment: Deleting GPIO.cleanup() won't help 
After that i enabled error messages, raspi says:
'RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use...'

Comment: Also looks like a typo in the last line, it says `PIO.output(17, 21, 22, True)` and should probably be `GPIO.output(...)`.

Comment: my fault :D Fixed

Comment: But still not working :/

Comment: You need to edit your question and say what isn't working.  No point in us guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You read through each line of a file, turning on various LEDs, but each loop happens so fast that you barely see anything happen. You need to move your `sleep` statement.

you can put it here:

```
for line in f:
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

...or better yet, put it at the very bottom of the `for()` loop so it sleeps after the line is processed. It should be indented only once inside the loop.

Comment: Thats not working, mabie better use 'while' than 'if' in first 'if' line?